# Is it possible to write Excel VBA Code in Visual Studio

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel

Is there a way to write VBA Code in Visual Studio. If not is there any other alternatives?

Comment: The VBA IDE in Office. Press F11 in an Office app.

Comment: @tonybd. Not sure that answers his question. All F11 does is open VBE. Not VS.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

VBA code for Excel can only be written inside Excel using the VBA IDE. VBA projects are stored as part of the Excel file and cannot be loaded into Visual Studio.

However, you can write VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) managed add-ins for Excel using Visual Studio. The following MSDN page covers both developing with VBA and VSTO.

[Excel for developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa905411.aspx)

You could also use the interop features of VBA to consume a (COM) object written in Visual Studio from your VBA code.

Comment: `VBA code for Excel can only be written inside Excel using the VBA IDE.` Not true. VBA can be written in any text editor and imported into a workbook's VBA project as `*.bas` and `*.cls` text files.

Comment: @ExcelHero Not only that, but it can be written in a text editor and written forcefully into the compressed VBAProject stream. [See here](https://github.com/bontchev/pcodedmp/issues/13#issuecomment-573294662)

Answer (score 79):

The best you can do is bend the office Visual Basic Editor (VBE) tool to your liking.  If you stay in it's native environment you get the full power of error detection, Intellisense, live code running, etc.

My tips...

1. In the VBE go to Tools > Options > Editor tab.
   Turn off 'Auto Syntax Check'. You still get code highlighted errors but no annoying popups.
2. Go to the Editor Format tab and change the Font to `Consolas (Western)`, Size `11`.
3. For code indenting install the awesome, free, [Code Manager](https://web.archive.org/web/20230124041102/http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/codemanager.htm). It adds some sick keyboard shortcuts.
   [image]
4. Make the [Edit toolbar easily accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874710/25197) for code commenting/uncommenting.
   [image]
5. Use [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) to add unit testing, source control, code inspections and refactoring functionality.

[image: Rubberduck Menu]

With those simple changes you end up with a half way decent, useful, and keyboard friendly environment to write your visually appealing code. :-D

[image]

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your answer, which really open my mind to the world.

Comment: Is there a comment/uncomment keyboard shortcut that I am missing?

Comment: @jonathanbell There isn't a great way to define a shortcut. Best way I know is to right click on the comment button, choose Customize, leave the dialog open and then right click the button again. From there you can add an `&` in front of the letter you want to use to trigger the button when pressed in combination with the `Alt` key. So... if you give it the name `Co&mment` then `Alt+M` will comment the code. Then name the other one `&Uncomment` and `Alt+U` will uncomment the code. Not great, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 6):

I've been looking for an answer to this question myself.

Best I've found myself is the option of exporting a Module ect from Excel with the code you've already written (or blank) and load that up in the Visual Studio Environment.

It doesn't offer much, but the highlighted text and auto indenting is nice and makes it much easier to read compared to the standard VBA environment.

Then once you're done just import it back into Excel.

Answer (score 6):

There is a VSCode extension to do this.
It allows you to write code in VSCode and export it to Excel.
This extension is very useful when you develop in VBA.

Here's the link to download the [XVBA extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=local-smart.excel-live-server)

**Edit :**

As [Peter Macej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217666/peter-macej) said in comment, this solution only works for [Visual Studio **Code**](https://code.visualstudio.com/) not for [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/fr/)

Comment: Just a note. It's a common mistake but Visual Studio Code is not Visual Studio. They are completely different applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly add and edit a VBA file (.vb) in your Visual Studio solution, but the intellisense will be worthless/screwed up.
This extension for **VScode** would probably provide a much better experience: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spences10.VBA

If your goal is have your VBA code exposed to source control so you can track changes, then it's still worth it to include in your Visual Studio solution, but just store that VBA code in a plain text file and then use the Excel interop to load it into the appropriate module within the excel workbook, e.g.:

```
xlWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents["ThisWorkbook"].CodeModule.AddFromFile(@"C:\PathToYour\VBAcode.txt");
```

And there are other methods to delete/replace code lines, etc....

Answer (score 1):

You can try the xlWings package for python and use it with VS Code https://youtu.be/xoO-Fx0fTpM

xlWings is a python module that allows to manipulate excel files from python and call python from excel. If you have it installed (see instructions here: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/installation.html) it provides a basic import/export interface that works pretty well with any external editor.

After you installed the xlWings addon for Excel (no Administrator rights required), you can then call `xlwings vba edit` in the shell. This will export all scripts from your excel file into text files, watch for changes and import them back into excel. With vsc autosave this results in minimal delays - it's possible to have the developer tools in excel open at the same time and the updated content appears there with a delay of a second or so.

This currently hits my personal sweet spot between complexity of setup and ease of use, though I wish that it would be somewhat configurable (e.g. to specify the directory the script files get exported to).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).