# Is there a way to comment a part of a line in Excel's VBA like c#

Tags: c#, vba, excel, comments

The equivalent in c# would be this :

```
string s = MyFonction(s /* .Replace("r","t") */ );
```

I am commenting only a part of the line, this way I can't forget the little add up I made, and I can reactivate it by removing /* and */

I would like to do the same in Excel's VBA :

```
ActiveCell'.Offset(1, 0)'.CurrentRegion.Select
```

I don't think there is a way to do this directly. Still, it would be extremely useful to be able to comment parts of the line...

Is there a way to at least simulate it ?

Comment: At first I was tempted to mark this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/24001501/1132334, which is itself a duplicate :) but your question is different. short answer: no.

Comment: I would just comment the entire line & put the modified line directly below it - you could then just swap which line is commented to restore the extra bit.

Comment: @PaulF It seems like a good way to go, thanks for the idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in VBA, you have to comment all the line

Comment: As far as I know, all VB flavors do not support this; not just VBA. It doesn't necessarily have to be the whole line. You can do it anywhere in the line, but there's no short terminating the comment.

Comment: You can add a comment to the end of a line without commenting it all. Note that this is not really an answer but more of a comment.

Comment: there are some VB/VBA syntax rules around commenting (line continuation inside comment, starting comment with `REM`, "empty" comments) but  none of them do what OP wants

Comment: in fact, it can be the whole line, OR the rest of the line