# Commenting / Uncomment VBA code in Excel for Mac 2016

Tags: excel, vba, macos, vbe

I've seen posts for how to comment / uncomment blocks of VBA code in Excel but they all seem to be related to Excel for Windows.  I can't figure out a similar method for commenting large blocks of code in Excel for Mac 2016.  Please help.

Here is the related post I found for Windows:
[How to comment and uncomment blocks of code in the Office VBA Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933279/how-to-comment-and-uncomment-blocks-of-code-in-the-office-vba-editor/12933280#12933280)

Comment: Just a note: the VBE (the VBA IDE) has nothing to do with its host - it's the same editor whether you're in Excel, Word, Outlook, PowerPoint, Sage300, AutoCAD, or whatever. The VBA editor on Mac is an entirely different thing though, even more severely under-featured than the VBE.

Answer (score 1):

The VBA editor in Office mac 2016 is severely broken. Office mac 2011 did have the ability to comment/uncomment code blocks.

MS have promised a fix, but none has yet arrived:

[Bring back a fully functional VBE (Visual Basic Editor for VBA)](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304933-excel-for-mac/suggestions/9098431-bring-back-a-fully-functional-vbe-visual-basic-ed)

Comment: "fully functional" as in "still won't support plug-ins but will let you comment code blocks"?

Comment: @Mat'sMug who knows, maybe the patch will be .NET Core Editor for Office (with a VBA converter), and debut on the mac. Or maybe not.

Comment: Since the Mac Office 2016 October release (October 10, 2017 V15.39.0 build 17101000), the VBA editor is improved a lot. See [release notes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Release-notes-for-Office-2016-for-Mac-ed2da564-6d53-4542-9954-7e3209681a41?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)